# Is it possible to find the changes of the debugged .exe file ollydbg?

Tags: ollydbg

I have two .exe files and one of them was debugged by someone, i want to compare it with the original one and find the codes that was changed, is it possible to do that ? If it's, how can i do it ?
( i mean just the changed codes only )

Comment: Start run cmd /k fc /b f#x.exe s#x.exe

Comment: I guess you wanted to say one of them is a *patched*, not *debugged*, version of the other?

Comment: kinda, patched, edited, can i find out the code that changed ?

Answer (score 1):

Open the patched file in OllyDbg. 
**Right click** on CPU pane and choose "**Select all**" from **Edit**.
Again right click on the CPU pane and select "Binary copy" or press **Ctrl+Insert**.

Close current session and open the original file.

**Right click** on CPU pane and choose "**Select all**" from **Edit**.
Again right click on the CPU pane and select "Binary paste" or press **Shift+Insert**.

Now from the CPU pane **right click** menu, select "**Search for**" then select "**All modifications**"
The result would be shown in a new window.

Comment: @GiaHuyTrần If it answers your question, please accept it. Thanks.